# wpf collections subproperty data binding path

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I am trying to achieve the something equivalent to the xpath function shown below but with wpf binding paths. Essentially I need to get the Name of the person within a collection list using only the ID of the person as a filter. I am not quite sure how to correctly construct the wpf path for that.

I have gone through some msdn posts, particularly this one: [binding_to_collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview#binding_to_collections), but as far as I can tell it only describes index based filtering.

```
//XPath that works with xmls
string xpath = "//People[ID='123456']/Name";

//My attempts at wpf path bindings
var binding = new Binding($"People[ID='123456'].Name");
var binding = new Binding($"People[ID='{personID}'].Name");
var binding = new Binding($"People[0].Name");//works but doesn't show correct person
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is nothing like `ID='123456'` supported for property binding paths in WPF or XAML. Indexes and compile-time constants are the only options.

For example, if `People` was a `Dictionary<int, Person>` you could bind to a specific `Person` based on a *constant* key (`123456`) like this:

```
People[123456].Name
```

But you cannot filter based on a property using a binding path. This is not supported.

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you know if this works with a dictionary of string, string?

Comment: @5tar-Kaster: Yes, it should.